# When trying to create new item in MERN stack, getting TypeError: this.props.meals.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, crud, mern

I've created a MERN with redux application where users can order a meal from a menu. In the admin side, I am providing delete and add functions so the meals on the menu can be changed all in the same page. I have managed to get the delete meal item to work, but I am getting the following error when I try and add a new meal item:

[image]

My redux action is as follows:

```
export const createMeal = (meal) => (dispatch) => {
  fetch("api/meals", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(meal),
  })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
      dispatch({ type: CREATE_MEAL, payload: data });
    });
};
```

In my server file, I have the following endpoint created in Express:

```
app.post("/api/meals", async (req, res) => {
  if (!req.body.title) {
    return res.send({ message: "Data is required." });
  }
  const newMeal = new Meal(req.body);
  const savedMeal = await newMeal.save();
  res.send(savedMeal);
});
```

My UpdateMenuScreen is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchMeals, deleteMeal, createMeal } from "../actions/mealActions";

class UpdateMenuScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      meal: null,
      showAddMenu: false,
      title: "",
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchMeals();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.props.fetchMeals();
  }

  handleInput = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  createMeal = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const meal = {
      title: this.state.title,
    };
    this.props.createMeal(meal);
  };

  deleteMeal(id) {
    this.props.deleteMeal(id);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Current Menu</h3>
        {!this.props.meals ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <ul className="meals">
            {this.props.meals.map((meal) => (
              <li key={meal._id}>
                <div className="meal">
                  <p>{meal.title}</p>
                  <button
                    className="button"
                    onClick={() => this.props.deleteMeal(meal._id)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ showAddMenu: true });
          }}
        >
          Add New Menu Item
        </button>
        {this.state.showAddMenu && (
          <div className="cart">
            <form onSubmit={this.createMeal}>
              <ul className="form-container">
                <li>
                  <label>Menu Item Title:</label>
                  <input
                    name="title"
                    type="text"
                    required
                    onChange={this.handleInput}
                  ></input>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button className="button primary" type="submit">
                    Save New Menu Item
                  </button>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </form>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect((state) => ({ meals: state.meals.items }), {
  fetchMeals,
  deleteMeal,
  createMeal,
})(UpdateMenuScreen);
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing? Or is it not possible to do this all on the same page?

EDIT:

I've console logged this.props.meals in ComponentDidMount and got the following results:

[image]

My mealsReducer is as follows:

```
const { FETCH_MEALS, DELETE_MEAL, CREATE_MEAL } = require("../types");

export const mealsReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_MEALS:
      return { items: action.payload };
    case DELETE_MEAL:
      return { items: action.payload };
    case CREATE_MEAL:
      return { items: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I also get this underneath my original error, could it be something in my mealActions that I don't have correct?

[image]

Comment: console that `this.props.meals`  first and what is the results of that?

Comment: I'm not sure where in my code to put a console log for that - please could you advise?

Comment: do `console.log(this.props.meals)` in `componentDidMount` and give us the results

Comment: edited my question to show the console log result, which shows the already existing meals in the menu. If I navigate to the home screen after the TypeError that comes up after trying to add a meal, the meal I tried to add now displays in a the list of the home page so it is saving to the database correctly. It just won't display on the UpdateMenuScreen for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to your reducer of meals and define the initial state of meals to `[]`

Comment: I've added my mealsReducer, where should i set the initial state?

Comment: look https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers#creating-the-root-reducer

Comment: I've added this to my reducer now but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: are you getting undefined first and after that you got array right? it shows in your output image!

Comment: I've just rerun this and not sure why i got undefined the first time, that isn't showing now

Comment: make demo of it in codesandbox and give us we will help you

Comment: I've figured it out! In my mealAction, I was trying to parse the response of my createMeal into a json, but it's not. I will update my question with what I've got working now and it works. Thank you for all your help along the way!

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your error.

```
render() {
    const { meals = [] } = this.props // default to empty array when it's undefined
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Current Menu</h3>
        {!meals.length ? (
          <div>Loading...</div>
        ) : (
          <ul className="meals">
            {meals.map((meal) => (
              <li key={meal._id}>
                <div className="meal">
                  <p>{meal.title}</p>
                  <button
                    className="button"
                    onClick={() => this.props.deleteMeal(meal._id)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </button>
                </div>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        )}
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            this.setState({ showAddMenu: true });
          }}
        >
          Add New Menu Item
        </button>
        {this.state.showAddMenu && (
          <div className="cart">
            <form onSubmit={this.createMeal}>
              <ul className="form-container">
                <li>
                  <label>Menu Item Title:</label>
                  <input
                    name="title"
                    type="text"
                    required
                    onChange={this.handleInput}
                  ></input>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <button className="button primary" type="submit">
                    Save New Menu Item
                  </button>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </form>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment, I've tried this and it doesn't render anything at all on my UpdateMenuScreen

Comment: This still doesn't work unfortunately, I get the same error TypeError: meals.map is not a function